# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

```
function readMessages(data, textStatus) 
{
    clearChat = data.clear;

    if (clearChat == 'true') {
        $('#chatmessageinner')[0].innerHTML = "";
        lastMessageID = -1;
    }

    if (data.messages.length > 0)
    {
        if(lastMessageID > data.messages[0].id) return;
        lastMessageID = data.messages[data.messages.length - 1].id;
    }

    $.each(data.messages, function(i, message) {
        var htmlMessage = "";
        htmlMessage += "<div class="item" style="color:" + message.color + "">";
        htmlMessage += "[" + message.time + "] " + message.name + " said: <br/>";
        htmlMessage += message.message;
        htmlMessage += "</div>";

        $('#chatmessageinner')[0].innerHTML += htmlMessage;
    });

}
```

This is function, error is:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
In line $.each(data.messages, function(i, message) {
```

What is wrong? Help me, please.

Comment: You need to escape the `"` characters in your HTML string. e.g. `class=\"item\"`

Comment: Or use single quotes: `'<div class="item" style="color:' + message.color + '">'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape your string:

```
htmlMessage += "<div class="item" style="color:" + message.color + "">";
```

This is wrong and should be:

```
htmlMessage += "<div class=\"item\" style=\"color:" + message.color + "\">";
```

Or, **better**, use the single quotes:

```
htmlMessage += '<div class="item" style="color:' + message.color + '">';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is this line

```
htmlMessage += "<div class="item" style="color:" + message.color + "">";
```

You're using double quotes inside double quotes, should be like

```
htmlMessage += "<div class=\"item\" style=\"color:" + message.color + "\">";
```

Answer (score 1):

The code building a string is a bit off.

```
$.each(data.messages, function(i, message) {
    var htmlMessage = "";
    htmlMessage += "<div class='item' style='color:" + message.color + "'>";
    htmlMessage += "[" + message.time + "] " + message.name + " said: <br/>";
    htmlMessage += message.message;
    htmlMessage += "</div>";

    $('#chatmessageinner')[0].innerHTML += htmlMessage;
});
```